# Registering Transaction Event Handlers in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I'm currently using Spring Data with Neo4j and have subclassed the `SpringRestGraphDatabase` to allow the registration of specific transaction event handlers.

I call the `registerTransactionEventHandler` method to do so. Unfortunately I always get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.AbstractRemoteDatabase.registerTransactionEventHandler(AbstractRemoteDatabase.java:52) ~[neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.6.jar:1.6]
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.registerTransactionEventHandler(RestGraphDatabase.java:28) ~[neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.6.jar:1.6]
```

By looking closely at the AbstractRemote I see that it always throws an exception:

```
public <T> TransactionEventHandler<T> registerTransactionEventHandler( TransactionEventHandler<T> tTransactionEventHandler ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

The `RestGraphDatabase` doesn't provide an implementation for the register method hence the exception. I'm not sure what alternatives to use, especially as I'm extending `SpringRestGraphDatabase`.

Is there a cleaner alternative?

(I'm using v2.1.0.M1)

Comment: This is still a very good question we could reformulate as : how to register a transaction event handler on an external neo4j database ? and how to make it stateful, as APOC seems to be stateless ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah,
the exposure of these handlers would be very costly over the network. Depending on what you want to do, I would suggest writing a custom plugin to expose your operations and register what you need via a REST endpoint, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-plugins.html

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. My first preference would've been to use the embeddded instance, however I'm using Heroku which really limits that.

Comment: Should've mentioned that the reason I'm using the event handler is to dynamically create Id's for the nodes. These are Id's that would be exposed to clients.